# Cannot resolve all parameters for error in angular2

Tags: angular

I have this array:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: Home, data: {cssClass: "glyphicon-home" } },
  { path: 'a', component: A, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data : {type: UserType.A, cssClass: "glyphicon-leaf"} },
  { path: 'b', component: B, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data : {type : UserType.B, cssClass: "glyphicon-th-list"} },
  { path: 'login', component: Login, data: {cssClass: "glyphicon-asterisk" }}
];
```

which uses AuthGuard. AuthGuard looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

So AuthGuard has AuthService in its constructor. AuthService is a class decorated with @Injectable() and it has some methods like login, logout and getRoutes(). I want to access the original routes const from the beggining of my post in getRoutes because here I want to access the routes and build the navigation menu based on them. But once I try to do that, I get the error 'Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AuthGuard'(undefined, Router)'. WHat I think is going on is: I use AuthGuard in routes, I use AuthService in AuthGuard and now I want to use routes in AuthService, so it's a circular reference.

What I want to do is avoid writing the routes in more than one place. How can I fix this?

Comment: do you import `autherService` and `Router` in `authgaurd.ts`?

Comment: @micronyks Yes.

Comment: @petko_stankoski Did you try to use a forwardRef to solve this?